# Designing a GUI to inspect MRI Stacks in MatLab

Tags: matlab, user-interface, imaging

I am currently trying to code a GUI which has two main functionalities. Firstly, it should be able to load a stack of images (there are 192 192x256 grayscale images) and make them browsable by moving a slider around. Secondly, whenever I click somewhere it should store the [x,y] coordinates of the image.

I thought I had a good understanding of how the GUI interacted with the code but writing callback functions is very confusing (this is my first time doing it). I was under the impression that callback functions are defined inline. Whenever I do this however I get an error message telling me: "Error: Function definitions are not permitted in this context."

Below is my code.

```
firstSlice = 1;
lastSlice = size(DicomImages,1);

h = figure('Toolbar', 'none',...
    'Menubar', 'none',...
    'Name', 'Slice Inspector',...
    'NumberTitle','off',...
    'IntegerHandle','off');


SliceSelector = uicontrol(h, 'Style', 'slider',...
    'Callback', @LoadNewImage);

set(SliceSelector, 'Value',firstSlice);
set(SliceSelector, 'Max', lastSlice);
set(SliceSelector, 'Min', firstSlice);

slice = get(SliceSelector, 'Value');

displayImage = imshow(DicomImages{1,firstSlice});
pixInfo = impixelinfo(displayImage);

set(displayImage,'ButtonDownFcn',@coordInfo);

function LoadNewImage( SliceSelector, eventdata, handles)
    slice = round(get(SliceSelector, 'Value') );
    imshow(DicomImages{1,slice});
end

function coordInfo( cursor, eventdata, handles)
    [x, y] = ginput(1);
end
```

When I run it I get the error message that I posted above. Any help/advice would be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are defining functions inside a script that created the GUI. This is invalid syntax in MATLAB. Functions can only be defined in a function file. You could solve your problem by making your script into a function, and then calling that function from the command line, or some script. 
Thus, you can add something like:

function guiSpawn

at the first line. The callbacks can be either nested functions or local functions to the file. See here for more details about functions in MATLAB:
http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/function.html

Comment: Sorry about that. Oversight on my part. However when I run the code (with the functions now in other files) I still get the same error. Below are my two functions.

`function [] =  LoadNewImage(SliceSelector, eventdata)

    slice = round(get(SliceSelector, 'Value') );
    imshow(DicomImages{1,slice});
    
end`

`function [x, y] =  coordInfo(cursor, eventdata)

    [x, y] = ginput(1);
    
end`

Comment: Ok i see. Can you see which line produces the error? It should be in the posted message.

Comment: Turns out after fixing the issues using your first suggestion it all worked out. Sorry for the late reply.

Answer (score 0):

It is even more confusing that GUIDE does not provide any "end" statement to the functions...

From what I understand, the callbacks are **local** functions and not **nested**.